# Web Api Cookies seems to return Cached Requests

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the following code in a WebApi Controller:

```
    public static T GetCookieValue<T>(this HttpRequestMessage request, string key)
    {
        var cookieCollection = request.Headers.GetCookies();

        Trace.TraceInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cookieCollection));

        foreach (var cook in cookieCollection.Select(c => c.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == key)).Where(cook => cook != null))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(cook.Value, typeof(T));
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

**Usage**

```
var myValue = this.Request.GetCookieValue<int>("activeTenant");
```

On the client side watching Fiddler I can see the value changing, however on the .NET side, it keeps giving me the same value over and over again.  Is there some sort of Cookie or Header Cache that is causing this?

Here is some more information that I sorta figured out.  My WebApi controller is inheriting from another and this call is in that base controller.  If I do the call in the Sub-Classed controller it works fine.  So now I am thinking this is Autofac handing me back cached requests??